# count on me / count me on

Tags: phrasal-verbs

Is there any difference between these two? For example, in reply to a message asking whether I am attending an event, what would be the right one to use? Can we use *count on me* / *count me* on interchangeably, or do they mean different things?

Comment: There is no idiom "*count me on*": you're probably thinking of "*count me **in***", which is relevant in this context. And while "you can *count on me*" and "you can *count me in*" are both valid, affirmative, responses to the question of "will you be attending the party?", more broadly they are different idioms which mean different things, and are usually employed in different contexts. They're both common enough that you can look them up in your favorite  dictionary, I bet.

Comment: Thanks a lot. My error was using "count me in" with the wrong preposition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you can respond with either of these, there is a difference in their meanings.

[**Count on someone (or something)**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+on)

> to rely on someone or something; to depend on someone or something.
>
> *We can count on Bill to get the job done.*

There's no *count me on* commonly used, but the closest thing is:

[**Count me in**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/count+me+in)

> include me in your activity or plan
>
> *You can count me in - I haven't been to a ballgame in years!*

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there is a difference between the two.

The first one, 'count on me', means that you are committing yourself to a cause, for example:

> "Can you go to the store and get some milk?" -> "You can count on me!"
>   "If you see the mail delivery van drive up, please come and get me!" -> "You can count on me."

While it can be used with 'attending an event', it is not as common as it has a different connotation at least.

The second, 'count me on' is incorrect, as the phrase is 'count me in'.
In case of attending an event, 'count me in' lets the other(s) know that you will be there, that you will join the people that extended the invitation, making this expression the most commonly used response in this context.